# Does Malcolm Tucker have children?

Tags: the-thick-of-it

In Season 3 of The Thick Of It, Malcolm is seen with kids paintings on his walls in his office, and when he goes to his house with the press following him, there is a kid looking out the window at him. He never mentions his kid(s) but does mention a niece...

In Season 4, in episode 6, he says "No family, no friends, well no real friends..." in his big rant to Ollie. He wears a wedding band throughout the series.

Does he have children or not?

Comment: An out-of-universe reason for the ring: When Capaldi started filming Doctor Who, he insisted on wearing his (real) wedding ring due to concerns about losing it during filming. It's likely the same applied to previous roles, including TTOI.